# How to change just a portion of a repeated column name r

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a data set that has multiple patterned column names, "tstpos_012720", and "pbpos_012720" basically one for each date. I want to rename them in such a way that I can have each pair ordered together.
I am looking for something where I can move the date to the front and add a "t" or "p" to the end.
Such that I go from "tstpos_012720, pbpos_012720" to "012720_t, 012720_p"

I am fairly new to R, but I couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: You can also use the regex `names(df) <- sub('(.).*_(\\d+)', '\\2_\\1', names(df))`

Answer (score 1):

With the values

```
x <- c("tstpos_012720", "pbpos_012720")
```

You can use `gsub` which takes a regular expression. You can use matching groups to extract and rearrange the parts you are interested in.

```
gsub("(.)[^_]*_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", x)
# [1] "012720_t" "012720_p"
```

for column names, you can do

```
names(mydata) <- gsub("(.)[^_]*_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", names(mydata))
```

Comment: I guess I should clarify a bit. The data frame I am working with has hundreds of columns repeating that pattern.
When I enter
`gsub("(.)[^_]*_(.*)", "\\2_\\1", WA_Cases)`
it fails to rename the columns. I am sure I am missing something.

Comment: Thank you so much. That second part did the trick.